# fatal error: SDL2/SDL_ttf.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to c++ and have run into this problem. I'm trying to simply include the header file SDL_tff.h but it can't be found. I am fairly sure I have installed correctly SDL2_ttf-2.0.14 and added the header to global search directory and library to linker tab in Code::Blocks. Also I have added -lSDL2_ttf under the other linker options in the linker setting tab. And put all the .dll files into the .exe directory. Can anyone help me work out why it can't be found?

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SLD_ttf.h" //fatal error: SDL2/SDL_ttf.h: No such file or directory

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    //TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Sans.ttf", 24);


    if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 480, 0, &window, &renderer) ==  0) {
        SDL_bool done = SDL_FALSE;

        while (!done) {
            SDL_Event event;

            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 220, 220, 220, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);


            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 10, 10, 630, 10);
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 630, 10, 630, 470);
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 630, 470, 10, 470);
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 10, 470, 10, 10);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    done = SDL_TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (renderer) {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    }
    if (window) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    }
}
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what do you have for your search directories in code::blocks (Codeblocks menu > Settings > Compiler > Search directories)?  Also, make sure that you are using the settings for all builds not just x86 or x64.

Comment: E:\Programming\SDL\SDL2-2.0.5\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 and E:\Programming\SDL\SDL2_ttf-2.0.14\i686-w64-mingw32\include

Comment: but it works now. I don't know why. I experimented with changing "SDL2/SDL_ttf.h" to "SLD2\SDL.h" (changed to backslash instead of forward slash.) It still didn't work but when i changed back to forward slash it worked. I dont know but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: "SDL2/SLD_ttf.h" has a typo, it should be "SDL2/SDL_ttf.h". But maybe when u were writing the question you made the typo